# Why does the script not understand that the data in MySQL has changed?

Tags: python, mysql

I have two codes, but I wrote the simplest one for an example. There are two files, in one an infinite loop, in the second just a string that updates the data. Here is the code:

```py
from database import db,c

c.execute("UPDATE designbase SET flag = 1 WHERE id = '501285409'")
db.commit()
```

And two:

```py
from database import db, c
import time

while True:
    c.execute("SELECT flag FROM designbase WHERE id = 501285409")
    print(c.fetchall())
    time.sleep(5)
```

So, after I change the data in the table, the code with a loop outputs the old value. How to fix it?

A new value should be output, but it is not output